# Finding a circular path in a list of dicts (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, path, circular-dependency

I have data that looks something like this

```
mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": None},
...
]
```

where the id is always the dict's position in the list.

The item_totals will be aggregated, and the "send_to_id" key affects how this aggregation occurs. Here, as the dict with "id" = 2 has "send_to_id" = 1, the dict with "id" = 1 is then what I'm calling a destination layer and the totals of these two items will be aggregated differently to normal.

What is not allowed is something circular like this, where item 1 points to item 2 and item 2 points to item 1.

```
mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": 2},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": None}
]
```

Or this, where it is still circular and takes three steps

```
mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": 3},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": 2}
]
```

Also an item cannot point to itself.

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I would like to take in a list of dicts like the above and find out if a circular path exists so I can provide an appropriate error message to the user. Can anyone help?
I'm trying to work out how to follow a path to the next item but it ties knots in my brain.

If it matters, the maximum length of the list will be about 50.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step might be to create a dictionary of just the maps. We can do that with a nice [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#dictionaries) (look below the second green code example block).

```py
def get_direct_mappings(data: list) -> dict: 
    return {d["id"]: d["send_to_id"] for d in data if d["send_to_id"] is not None}
```

Now we have a slightly more easily solved problem, and we can use [previously made solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660117/9158985) to help us out. Specifically, we can basically just re-use the solution as posted after "**Update**", and add our above code to it.

```py
def find_cycles(original_data: list) -> list:
    n = {d["id"]: d["send_to_id"] for d in original_data if d["send_to_id"] is not None}
    cycles = []
    while n:
        visited = {}
        count = 0
        k, v = n.popitem()
        while v is not None:
            # visited[k] = (count, v)
            visited[k] = count
            count += 1
            k = v
            v = n.pop(k, None)

        if k in visited:
            if len(visited) == 1:
                cycle = tuple(visited.keys())
            else:
                cycle_start = visited[k]
                cycle = sorted((c, k) for k, c in visited.items() if c >= cycle_start)
                cycle = tuple(k for c, k in cycle)
                k = min(range(len(cycle)), key=lambda x: cycle[x])
                cycle = cycle[k:] + cycle[:k]
                cycles.append(cycle)

    return cycles
```

While it's not the prettiest, it works.

```py
mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": 3},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": 2}
]
print(find_cycles(mydict))
# prints [(1, 3, 2)]

mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": 2},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": None}
]
print(find_cycles(mydict))
# prints [(1, 2)]

mydict = [
    {"id": 0, "item_total": 10000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 1, "item_total": 15000, "send_to_id": None},
    {"id": 2, "item_total": 30000, "send_to_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "item_total": 20000, "send_to_id": None},
]
print(find_cycles(mydict))
# prints []
```

Comment: Oh amazing. I did have a look around but wasn't sure how to google for this. Thanks!